# Collection of related datasets (akin to transfer learning)

Tags: data-request, machine-learning

I am trying to do a certain kind of evaluation (not worth detailing here), and I am on the lookout for a collection of related datasets.

Allow me this simplistic (and unrealistic perhaps) example in order to clarify what I am looking for:

- Imagine having multiple "[Iris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_flower_data_set)" datasets.
- Each of these datasets measures the same thing. By this I mean the same (type and number) of features appear in all the datasets, and they are associated with the same kind of target (regression value/label).
- In the case, of the Iris dataset this would mean, that in all datasets, the data items are composed of the same four features and all associated with one of the three labels. The distribution of features, however, in each dataset can be different (also the proportion of classes can be different).
  Is anybody aware of such a collection of datasets?

So far I have been looking into transfer learning literature, but have not managed to find something like this so far.

ps. This question was previously posted on the Data Science forum where it was deemed off-topic.